# How can I develop mobile application using C# or anything else

Tags: c#

I need help, I am newbie in C#, I have developed one game application using C#, now I want to deploy that game in mobile application or any social application...How can I do that?

Comment: What does "... in mobile application or any social application" mean?

Answer (score 3):

There's also [monodroid](http://monodroid.net/), for C# on Android, and [monotouch](http://monotouch.net/) for iOS.

Answer (score 1):

Get the Windows Phone 7 SDK and start having fun. You see, each main player in the mobile area has a different platform:

- Windows Phone 7: C# and Silverlight
- Android: Java
- iPhone: Objective-C

Comment: Yep. All apps must be **completely** rewritten from scratch in those languages when ported to another device, no matter how much time or money it takes. Completely, and they **must use the vendor's SDK**. I'm using 'must' here instead of 'should,' because 'should' is not true enough.

Answer (score 0):

[mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) is what you are searching:

> Mono is a software platform designed
>   to allow developers to easily create
>   cross platform applications. Sponsored
>   by Novell (http://www.novell.com/),
>   Mono is an open source implementation
>   of Microsoft's .NET Framework based on
>   the ECMA standards for C# and the
>   Common Language Runtime. A growing
>   family of solutions and an active and
>   enthusiastic contributing community is
>   helping position Mono to become the
>   leading choice for development of
>   Linux applications.

You can use [monodroid](http://monodroid.net/) for **Android** and [monotouch](http://monotouch.net/) for **iOS** and well [Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402523%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) for **Windows Phone 7**. You will need some **$$$** just in case you didnt know.

***in other words***:   You can use **C#** on Android and iOS with [mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page), this will help you and your apps.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

For Nokia cellphones there are different Java SDKs like [S24 series SDK](http://www.forum.nokia.com/info/sw.nokia.com/id/cc48f9a1-f5cf-447b-bdba-c4d41b3d05ce/Series_40_Platform_SDKs.html)